# Trying to populate html select with ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to populate my select in html using ng-repeat, but it does not work. I observed that my ng-repeat appears to be commented when i inspect my browser.

My html:

```
 <select ng-model="transportcompanies" ng-options="TransportCompany in transportcompanies" value="{{TransportCompany.denumire}}">
    <option>{{ TransportCompany.denumire }}</option>
  </select>
```

My get service from server.js:

```
app.get('/#!/races/insert', (req, res) => {
  TransportCompany.findAll({
    attributes: ['id_firma', 'denumire']
  })
  .then((transportcompanies) => {
    res.status(200).send(transportcompanies)
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.warn(error)
      res.status(500).send('error')
    })
})
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('raceModule').controller('racesInsertController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {

const SERVER = 'https://proiectweb-sebastianburchi.c9users.io/#!'



    let $constuctor = () => {
        $http.get(SERVER + '/races/insert')
            .then((response) => {
              $scope.race=response.data
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }

  $constuctor()

  $scope.open = function($event,opened) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope[opened] = true;
  };

   $scope.getTemplate = (TransportCompany) => {

        return 'display'
    }

}])
```

i have edit my post trying to work with ng-options.Ng-repeat is not working. Now it displays me, but i have TransportCompany.denumire as option..not it's value

Comment: remove `{{}}`, its should be like `value="TransportCompany.denumire"`

Comment: @gauravbhavsar still doesnt work, ng-repeat is stil commented in my browser

Comment: please show us your ngController code, where you define transportcompanies ?

Comment: Try change the `ng-model` of option to som other name.

Comment: sorry have you tried to just remove the string hard coded? and put {{TransportCompany.denumire}}

Comment: Please post the code of your controller

Answer (score 0):

TRY This

```
                <option ng-repeat="TransportCompany in    transportcompanies">     {{TransportCompany.denumire}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the same name for both ng-repeat iterator object and options. So, when you select an option from select list, the value over writes. So, change the names to some other as:

```
<select ng-model="transportcompanies">
   <option ng-repeat="TransportCompany in transportcompanies" value="{{TransportCompany.denumire}}">TransportCompany.denumire</option>
</select>
```

to:

```
<select ng-model="someothername">
   <option ng-repeat="TransportCompany in transportcompanies" value="{{TransportCompany.denumire}}">TransportCompany.denumire</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is it showing  any console errors or where it goes wrong?

Comment: Will you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" ng-value="option.html">
      {{option.display}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Please refer to the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/EgOJaWCjQtv7jDB5RS39?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please maintain the naming conventions. Apart of that, below should be working fine:

```
<select ng-model="transportcompanies">
   <option ng-repeat="TransportCompany in transportcompanies" value="{{TransportCompany.denumire}}">{{TransportCompany.denumire}}</option>
</select>
```

For your reference : [Plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/V2NswuNxJEz5YHZEISrE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your response data if assigned to `$scope.race`, so try to iterate on `race`.

```
<select ng-model="transportcompanies" ng-options="TransportCompany in race" value="{{TransportCompany.denumire}}">
  <option>{{ TransportCompany.denumire }}</option>
</select>
```